# Can desirable Stack Overflow tags be auto-added to posts?

Tags: discussion, tags

Suggested tags for questions are already computed when editing a question. Could questions be automatically added to posts instead of merely suggesting them?

Such auto-generated tags could be added without human control, but marked as auto-generated, waiting for some human to confirm/reject them.

The problem this would solve is that tags are used for filtering, but human editors will typically choose 1-3 tags based on their common-sense, laziness, humility, and what they had for breakfast. That means questions get under-tagged, and thus end up in wrong lists.

Another problem this solves is that authors cannot know the whole space of tags and which of tag synonyms are most appropriate for their question. The effect is again the same, the question will not pass the filters of other users adequately.

Also this would hopefully reduce time spent by editors on fixing bad tagging.

Comment: Re *"Could questions be automatically added to posts..."*. Don't you mean *"Could tags be automatically added to posts..."*?

Comment: changed the title as suggested

Answer (score 4):

This already happens; the system tries to predict tags based on the question and suggests them to the author when they go to fill in the tags field. Here's what that looks like for [a question I picked arbitrarily from the front page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614260/adding-frame-with-options-to-menu-button):

[image: suggested tags: css html javascript jquery]

Note that although [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) is suggested, the question is *not* actually about jQuery; it just happens to contain a large number of keywords that are frequently used in existing questions tagged [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery). This is why predicted tags are *suggested* but not automatically imposed.

See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/suggested-tags/info

Comment: thanks, removed most of my question. Sorry I did not see these suggestions before.